# Converting copy to clipboard jQuery code to plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am converting below jQuery code to plain JavaScript. [code pen here](https://codepen.io/basirpayenda/pen/JjGMXrL?editors=1010) and [here](https://codepen.io/dejanstojanovic/pen/PZJVRr?editors=1010) is the original jQuery version of it.

```
function CopyToClipboard(value, showNotification, notificationText) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val(value).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
    ....
```

my code converting it to JavaScript.

```
function CopyToClipboard(value, showNotification, notificationText) {
    var $temp = document.querySelector("<input>");
    document.body.append($temp);
    $temp.value.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.removeElement();
    ...
```

this is the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '<input>' is not a valid selector.
```

edited:

```
function CopyToClipboard(value, showNotification, notificationText) {
    const inputElem = document.createElement('input');
    inputElem.value = value;    
    var $temp = document.querySelector("<input>");
    document.body.append($temp);
    $temp.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(el);
```

Comment: Dont you want something like `document.createElement("INPUT")` ?

Comment: jQuery code didn't do it, but I think that is necessary. yes

Comment: I added `document.createElement('input')` before selecting it also, but it didn't work. I thought maybe I am missing something

Comment: I added a link of code pen above

Comment: https://codepen.io/dejanstojanovic/pen/PZJVRr?editors=1010

the jQuery implimentation of it

Comment: You need to use createElement. If it did not work, there might be other errors. querySelector is not a substitute. One other error is you did not assign the bale to input element.

Comment: Can anyone make that jQuery function work for me in plain JavaScript please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for your mentioned part of your code you need to change some more code in your codebase.

- First of you need to know `$("<input>")` will create an input element, where the equivalent of it in plain javascript is `document.createElement("input")`.
- `$temp.val(value).select();` will do two action in one line, first setting the function `value` parameter `input` value and last will select the value of that by `select()`. So to translate it into javascript we need to do this two action like this:

```js
$temp.value = value;
$temp.select();
```

- And at last you need to remove that input element with `remove()` instead of `removeElement()`.

The final result will be something like this:

```js
document.querySelector("#copymanager").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  CopyToClipboard(document.location.href, true, "Value copied");
});

function CopyToClipboard(value, showNotification, notificationText) {
  var $temp = document.createElement("input");
  document.body.append($temp);
  $temp.value = value;
  $temp.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();

  if (typeof showNotification === "undefined") {
    showNotification = true;
  }
  if (typeof notificationText === "undefined") {
    notificationText = "Copied to clipboard";
  }

  var notificationTag = document.createElement("div");
  notificationTag.className = "copy-notification";
  notificationTag.innerText = notificationText;

  if (showNotification) {
    document.body.append(notificationTag);
    notificationTag.style.display = "block";
    notificationTag.style.transition = "opacity 1s";

    setTimeout(function() {
      notificationTag.style.opacity = "0";
      notificationTag.remove();
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
.copy-notification {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -85px;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button id="copymanager">Click to copy to clipboard</button>
```

**Live demo:** [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/smalikss/pen/ZEQvewb)

Comment: kindly do a favor and convert the rest of the code to javascript as well.

Comment: @BasirPayenda I just add the description for you, that may help.

Comment: @BasirPayenda No worries, you can check the latest update in both answer and live demo now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
copyLink (url) {
    const el = document.createElement('textarea');
    el.value = url;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(el);
},
```

Comment: I created the `input` element. append it to the body. then selected it using `querySelector` it didn't work. kindly try converting my function to plain javascript

Comment: You cannot use querySelector like this. Check docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

P.S. You have to create this element, set the value you want, insert it into your DOM,  select and copy... then, remove.

Comment: I did exactly as you said, please visit the updated question. Still same error.

Comment: Nope, you have mistakes there. I fixed them, but now I dont't know how to save that pen)). Will give you link in few minutes.

Comment: Got it. Created account. Check the fixed code here: https://codepen.io/nicolaecasir/pen/Rwrxpdy

Comment: upvote. I really appreciate it brother, by the way I couldn't open above link in edit mode. I got my answer